# It has been a long time I havent used windows XP

Tags: word-usage

Want to know what does this sentence mean.
It has been a long time I havent used windows XP..
Does this means he is using it now?

Comment: This is a typical sentence from a non-native English speaker who has probably partly translated the sentence from their own language. While the general meaning is  clear, it is impossible to tell for sure whether they are now using XP: probably not (on the basis of real-world knowledge). In French the corresponding idiom would be _C'est longtemps depuis que je n'utilise pas ..._ "It is long since I do not use ..."  The perfect tenses are definitely English, but I would guess that the negative "haven't used" is a calque from French, or another language which behaves in this way.

Comment: Where did you read this sentence? There should also be an apostrophe in "haven't"

Comment: Idiomatic English would be: "I have not used XP in a long time." or "It's been a long time since I last used XP."  There is no implication that the speaker is using XP at the moment.

Comment: Nah i dint read it any where...i just heard it from a non native...so just wanted to check if its right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement isn't grammatically correct, so I'd have to guess at what he means. Possibly: "It has been a long time since I've used Windows XP".

That would most likely imply that he is using it now.

However it could also technically mean he's just thinking about how he hasn't used for some time - perhaps he is planning on using it soon, or again in the future.

In short, to know for sure, you'll probably need to ask.

Comment: Ohh...so here you mean he may start using it or may be he is using it right?

Comment: Yes. However, I am only guessing what the statement is likely to have meant, because the grammar wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

That sentence isn't quite valid. It could have been intended as:

> **For** a long time, I haven't used Windows XP.

meaning that he used it a long time ago and hasn't used it since. A better formulation of that could be:

- It has been a long time since I used Windows XP.
- I haven't used Windows XP in a long time.

---

I guess it could have been intended as:

> It has been a long time **since** I haven't used Windows XP.

That's a rather tortured sentence, but technically it means the speaker *has* been using XP continuously for a long time.

Comment: Oh okk..so it means he started using it after a long time again now

Comment: @user3608985 No, as stated it means that he's been using it all along. As I guess it was intended, it means that he used it a long time ago and hasn't used it since. I don't see it implying that he has used it again recently.

Comment: Oops, I slightly misread the sentence. I have updated the answer to reflect your actual question.